# How to read Facebook Comment based on updated time using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to read Facebook comments based on updated time through Graph API?.

I was using `FQL` to fetch the comments but, FB recently announced that `FQL` are not part of `V2.1`. So I need to use `Graph API`.

Is there any way I can fetch the comments based on updated_time?

**My query was like this**:

```
$fqlarray['getPhotoIDComments'] = "
    SELECT object_id 
    FROM comment 
    WHERE (object_id in (
        SELECT object_id FROM photo 
        WHERE owner='". $fqlvals['owner']."' 
            AND modified >='" . $fqlvals['modified']  . "' 
        LIMIT 10000)
    ) 
    ORDER BY time DESC 
    LIMIT 10000";
```

Thanks,
Suresha Posavalike

Comment: Here i can fetch the list Comments from specific time interval, Need to know same functionality exists in the Graph API too

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Graph API v2.0 app, you can continue to use FQl until August 7th, 2016. Currently, there's no equivalent in the Graph API as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks. We are planning to update our app by end of this year.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... Update what?

Comment: I mean we are moving to Graph API v2.1 app.

Comment: Why would you do that now? Is there any functionality you need to have from v2.1? If not, I'd wait with upgrading until the functionality is available...